# Convert and save date with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date, jpa

I have in spring a form with date when I enter the data in field date with datepicker and I give you save receipt the date format as follows E MMM dd HH: mm: ss Z yyyy example Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012 The tranformo with

```
         SimpleDateFormat formDate = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
         String birthday = formDate.format (emp.getBirthday ());
```

Returns a string if I then do

```
         Emp.setBirthday (formDate.parse (birthday));
```

I will return it E MMM dd HH: mm: ss Z yyyy and I need it in Date dd/MM/YYYY format to save it in the database

I have the class entity employed

```
public class Employees  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private int employeeId;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private Date birthday;

//getter and setter

}
```

and controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(ModelMap modelMap, @ModelAttribute("emp") Employees emp, BindingResult result) {
            SimpleDateFormat formaDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String birthday = formaDate.format(emp.getBirthday());

            emp.setBirthday(formaDate.parse(birthday));

            employeesServices.saveRecord(emp);
}
```

To save gives me the following error

> Value greater than specified precision allowed for this column

I am new enspring mvc

Translated with google translate

Comment: i would suggest adding jpa / hibernate tags as eventually the problem was regarding the use of those API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your `birthday` field is of java.util.Date type.

Then according to the JPA specification it must be annotated with a @Temporal.

> This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties
>   of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. It may only be
>   specified for fields or properties of these types. The Temporal
>   annotation may be used in conjunction with the Basic annotation, the
>   Id annotation, or the ElementCollection annotation (when the element
>   collection value is of such a temporal type.

As you want to cut the time from your date you should:

**1)** use java.sql.Date as your type

```
private java.sql.Date birthday;
```

**2)** or add this annotation:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthday;
```

Here is the snipped from the documentation for further info:

> In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined.
>   When dealing with temporal data you might want to describe the
>   expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, or both). Use
>   the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, use it
@Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
Private Date birthday;

Comment: @Maciej , how can i get .getYear() , .getMonth() from that `Date` class , any idea. Thanks